# how to unit test angular form validation conditions with jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am finding it difficult to pass the unit test for the following form validation function:

```
 isValid(fields: string) {
    let errorDisplay='';
    if (this.formGroup.controls[fields].status == 'INVALID') {
      if (this.formGroup.controls[fields]?.errors?.required) {
        errorDisplay = 'Please provide valid ' +fields;
      } else if (this.formGroup.controls[fields]?.errors?.minlength) {
        errorDisplay = fields+' should have min. ' +this.formGroup.controls[fields]?.errors?.minlength?.requiredLength + ' characters';
      } else if (this.formGroup.controls[field]?.errors?.maxlength) {
        errorDisplay = fields+' should have max. ' +this.formGroup.controls[fields]?.errors?.maxlength?.requiredLength + ' characters';
      } else {
        errorDisplay = 'Please provide valid ' +fields;
      }
    }
  }
```

the unit test that I have written, which throws error

```
 it('should execute  isFieldValid() function', () => {
    let errorDisplay:any;
    component.isValid('name');
    expect(component.formGroup.controls['name']?.errors?.required).toBeTruthy();
    expect(errorDisplay).toEqual('Please provide valid ' + 'name');
  });
```

error is:
[image]

I am new to testing , would appreciate the help in advance, for guidance and explanation.

Comment: Is your formGroup is initiated before used ?

Comment: yes i have initiates the formGroup.
export class FormComponent implements OnChanges {
 formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

Comment: Are you getting value in your first expect before match to toBeTruthy() ?
you can check using console log. 
Also Please share some more details to better understanding. Thanks!

Comment: I am creating a dynamic form, where i am trying to display the error messages using the above code.

Comment: Please share more details for this error to understand. 
If you are using Jasmine for testing then you can add a console.log in your test case  and check in test case Browser. You can also debug your code from there. Thanks!